# Trouble with Azure API Management TRACE policy rule not expanding variables in the message

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-api-management, variable-expansion

Following the instructions from this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions and this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#Trace ,  I am trying to define a TRACE policy rule in my inbound APIM API policy.

My rule looks like this but when it shows up in Application Insights, the variable hasn't expanded, not even if I use the simplest rule `@(true)` .  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions

Here is my policy:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <trace source="me-apim.azure-api.net" severity="information">
            <message>Requesting User: @(context.User)</message>
        </trace>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <forward-request />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong that causes the variable to not expand?

UPDATE:  I found I was able to get this one to work.  This suggests to me that maybe I am merely interacting with the `context` object incorrectly?

```
<trace source="me-apim.azure-api.net" severity="information">
    <message>@( string.Join(":", "Current Time", DateTime.UtcNow) )</message>
</trace>
```

NOTE: Super helpful things I learned while working on this:

1. Using VS Code as an APIM debugger works like a charm.
2. The Azure ADO UX has a "snippets" thing that is really helpful when creating policy rules.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, such variable expansion does not work at all, no matter the policy you try.  The whole value should be either a constant or expression, not text with expression inside it. I.e., instead of:

```
<message>Requesting User: @(context.User)</message>
```

you could use as you found out:

```
<message>@( string.Join(":", "Current Time", DateTime.UtcNow) )</message>
```

Or a bit simpler using string interpolation:

```
<message>@($"Current Time:{DateTime.UtcNow})</message>
```

Or more specifically to original problem:

```
<trace source="me-apim.azure-api.net" severity="information">
    <message>@("Requesting User: " + context.User.Id)</message>
</trace>
```

or:

```
<trace source="me-apim.azure-api.net" severity="information">
    <message>@($"Requesting User: {context.User.Id}")</message>
</trace>
```

Comment: If this is true, it greatly reduces the usefulness of the logging.  There must be a better approach that gives me what I need?   For example, what if I want to log performance metrics from response metrics found in the outbound context?

Comment: Not sure I understand how does it reduce usefulness. You still can log dynamic data, just have to use full expression for that.

Comment: What do you mean by "full expression".   The reason for my original question is because full expressions did not work for me.   Do you have a more specific answer?

Comment: I still don't understand the problem, but I've updated the answer with an example on how to log user Id. Hope that helps.